# Heroku custom DNS API route issue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, routes

I have a custom domain set up in Heroku which works fine.
I can access my site using both my app name and custom domain.
I can access a route using my standard Heroku URL, but not using the custom domain.

For example:

## Works:

```
https://{myappname}.herokuapp.com
https://{myappname}.herokuapp.com/callback
https://{customdomain}.com
```

## Does not work:

```
https://{customdomain}.com/callback
```

## Server config:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");;
const callback = require("./callback");
const app = express();

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve static assets if in production
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use("/callback", callback);

// Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
 });
}

// Init server/port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its too late but I am writing for those who face this issue in the future.

I was also facing this issue and solved through this.

### Was Not Working

```
https://{customdomain}.com/callback
```

### This Worked for me.

```
https://www.{customdomain}.com/callback
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, it was pretty simple and I feel stupid, however I will answer this here in case anyone ever has the same issue.

## Problem:

I had a React route/component called Callback. This React component was calling a Node.js route also called Callback, which processes information then redirects to a new React route/component.

Simple fix was to change my React route/component to callbackPage, leaving my Node.js route as Callback.

So in summary, I had a webpage URL with the same name as a server API route. when I visited this page, instead of the page being rendered, the API route was run and basically did nothing and timed out. I'm still confused as to why it worked with my app URL but not my custom domain.